# "Pairwise independent" is weaker that "independent"

Tags: probability

Can someone please give me a reference  to an (simple, realworld, i.e. not constructed) example of a discrete probability space such that there are three events in it that are pairwise independent but all three together are not independent (although I wouldn't mind, if someone would give me the example as an answer).

Comment: another example of not googling first...

Comment: 1) For my defense: I did google it -albeit not that long - but dismissed wikipedia a priori. Nonetheless I think -4 votes in  a couple of minutes for a legitimate question is harsh and not entirely justifiable I think! $$ $$ 2) The example in Wikipedia does it's just, but it is very artificial/constructed! I would like a more natural example, that can be taken from a real-world scenario (I know, should specified this from the beginning - but thats still not an excuse for the people who brutally voted down)

Comment: There are really quite a lot of good math articles in wikipedia, though typesetting is an issue, and some statements does not have proofs. You should take a look before you raise a question like this.

Comment: @user26698: I've voted up your comment, but in general you'll get better answers if you mention what you've tried (e.g. "I looked at wikipedia and found the example artificial".)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [standard example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence) involves tossing $2$ fair coins. For a more symmetrical example, toss $3$ fair coins. Let $A$ be the event Toss $1$ and Toss $2$ give the same result, $B$ be the event Toss $2$ and Toss $3$ give the same result, and $C$ the event Toss $3$ and Toss $1$ give the same result.

We have $\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)=\Pr(C)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B\cap C)=\Pr(C\cap A)=\frac{1}{4}$.

However, it is clear that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are not mutually independent.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability%29#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$